# ros_package_path

Tags: ros, package, ros-package-path, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can you tell me the default ROS_PACKAGE_PATH please?

Also, is the faulty ROS_PACKAGE_PATH the reason why I continue receiving the error "No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names" while I'm trying to install the joy package?

Thank you!

Soe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9766/ros_package_path/) by [soetommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/442/soetommy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2011-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is documented on the wiki [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PACKAGE_PATH)

The first few [beginner tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) walk you through how to manage your path.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no specific 'default ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'. It would depend on your distribution and method of installing ROS. On my ubuntu machine, it is /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks

You might try running 'locate setup.bash' (or zsh) to find your ros installation if you do not know where it it. Sourcing that file ('source setup.bash') should set the appropriate package path for that ros installation.

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2011-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-04-25**:
sorry for the confusion, I've removed setup.bash from gazebo in trunk.  They will not be there in the next release.

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-04-19**:
Does it also have /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash? That file should be there, I'd think (the gazebo one isn't too important). The arguments can't be parsed part could be because your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is set wrong, or because you've got the install command wrong. What command are you running?

**Comment by [soetommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/442/soetommy/) on 2011-04-19**:
Hi Murph,

Thanks for the suggestion.

When I tried "locate setup.bash", it returns "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/setup.bash". Is it working correctly?

Also, can you also explain me on the second part of the previous question: Why do it keep stating "No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names" while I'm trying to install the joy package?

Soe